# How to group pandas Series values by DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Series:

```
date_time
2018-05-03 07:46:03    1.0
2018-05-03 07:47:03    1.0
2018-05-03 08:33:03    1.0
2018-05-03 08:34:03    1.0
2018-05-03 08:35:03    1.0
```

It has the DatetimeIndex `date_time`.
I need to group values by `date_time` and count the number of groups. The groups should be created in such a way that the difference between `date_time` should be +/- 1-3 minutes in the same group. 
In the above-shown example, I have 2 groups:

Group 1

```
2018-05-03 07:46:03    1.0
2018-05-03 07:47:03    1.0
```

Group 2

```
2018-05-03 08:33:03    1.0
2018-05-03 08:34:03    1.0
2018-05-03 08:35:03    1.0
```

Therefore the answer should be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try pd.Grouper, date_time must be in datetime format. The following time is set to '3T' or 3 minutes.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_time', freq='3T', axis=1)).head(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question fully but something like this might help you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"value":[1,1,1,1,1]},
                  index=[dt.datetime(2018,5,3,7,46,3), dt.datetime(2018,5,3,7,47,3), 
                         dt.datetime(2018,5,3,8,33,3), dt.datetime(2018,5,3,8,34,3),
                         dt.datetime(2018,5,3,8,35,3)])

#Groups the data into 3min (180sec) buckets by count
df.resample("180S").count()

#Filter out rows with value 0 (adding to line above)
df.resample("180S").count()["value"].where(lambda x: x > 0)

#Drop NaN values and get length of the remaining df (which should equal your number of groups, in your case 2)
df.resample("180S").count()["value"].where(lambda x: x > 0).dropna().shape[0]
```

Hope this helps